# Looking for bibliography for rational approximation of integrals

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, book-recommendation, approximation-theory

I'm searching some information (with no success) about the state of the art of rational approximation of integrals, if such thing exists. That is, if there is some theory and methods to approximate some families of integrals by a rational number.

This would be in contrast to other ways to approximate integrals like the Simpson's rule, or computational methods like the Montecarlo method and similar ones.

Comment: Do you mean "rational function" rather than "rational number"?